# how do I traverse an android JSONArray witin a JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSONObject with the data structure as follows

```
[{"distance":"200 meters","location_id":"519"},{"distance":"300 meters","location_id":"219"}]
```

and I'm trying to traverse each array within that object, I have the following code where locationArray is the valid JSONObject

```
for (int j = 0; j < locationArray.length(); j++) {

     JSONObject j_obj;
     j_obj = locationArray.getJSONArray(j); //error here
     location_id = j_obj.getString("location_id");
}
```

but i'm getting an error trying to find each sub array of locationArray with an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution:

```
JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
int len = rootArray.length();
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    JSONObject obj = rootArray.getJSONObject(i);
    location_id = obj.getString("location_id");
}
```

There is an error in your code.  `j_obj = locationArray.getJSONArray(j);` should be `j_obj = locationArray.getJSONObject(j);`, as the object wrapped with curly braces represents a `JSONObject` and not a `JSONArray`

Edit:  you may consider using `obj.optString("location_id");` to avoid a potential problem